# Failed to set up alexa on rpi3. I get just one final error at the end despite build successful

Tags: raspbian, linux, pi-3

[image: Asks for authentification every time]

Because I get no text in the error I can't say what caused it. I don't have an usb mic yet (shipping from China takes 2 months). I followed this guide https://github.com/amzn/alexa-avs-raspberry-pi/blob/master/README.md
I forced audio through the 3.5 mm jack which has a built in mic. I'm trying this on my new rpi3. I have to mention as well, I have to set the maven path every time I restart. All together I wasted at least 5 hours trying to install this. It's very complicated and tedious, has 9000 steps, do not recommend it.

Comment: Here is the error output.
http://pastebin.com/74RvVP7C

Comment: The 3.5 mm jack does not have a built in mic.

Comment: I worded that badly, I meant to say I have earphones connected which come with a mic.

Comment: The 3.5mm jack is output only, you cannot connect a mic to it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It worked after I added an usb microphone.